# how to build and link a library to a project in Qt for WIndows?

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator, esri

I'm developing a simple Qt GUI application in Windows. The application itself has to open shapefile file type, and lurking around the internet, I've found two possible candidate libraries:

1. [shapelib C library](http://shapelib.maptools.org/)
2. [GDAL C++ Library](https://gdal.org/)

The problem I'm facing is that I can't make them to work in Qt, no matter what. I was more keen on using shapelib because of its smaller size, but in the end I only need something that works.

The steps I've done so far were:

- set up the main project, fine
- create a library project in Qt, add the source code for shapelib (build with cmake), fine, it builds without errors in Qt
- flag, in main project, the "shapelib" project as a dependency for main project
- add shapelib to .pro via SUBDIRS

If I try to include the main header from shapelib (shapefil.h), Qt gives "File not found" error and I can't work.

I'm not a Windows user, and quite new to Qt, I've read some of the documentation regarding how to add libraries on Qt website, but I'm more confused now than before.

Could you help me resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about Qt-Creator? The `Qt` tag is for the framework not the IDE. The `Qt-Creator` tag is for the IDE.

Comment: I think you are talking about the IDE and you should add your `.pro` file so someone that uses Qt-Creator can help. I am a Qt developer on windows (since 2008 at work) but I don't use Qt-Creator, QMake or .pro files often. I use CMake and develop in Visual Studio.

Comment: You need to tell the compiler where to find includes.

Comment: dont use '''SUBDIRS'''. try '''INCLUDEPATH''' ,'''LIBS'''

Comment: @drescherjm I'm working using Cmake, no .pro file in my project

Comment: You should use find_package() and possibly target_include_directories. If the CMake config file is properly setup linking to the proper CMake target (not usually the name of the lib file may have :: in the name) using target_link_libraries will setup the include directories. If that does not work there is target_include_directories()